# How to implement Array.prototype.sort default compare function?

Tags: javascript, sorting

### Background

I need to implement a function with the same behaviour as the default compare function of Array.prototype.sort

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

After reading the documentation I stumbled upon this:

> The default sort order is according to string Unicode code points.

What does this mean? Does it mean I convert every object to a string?

If so, assuming I have the array `[2, "a", { hello: "world" }]` would these steps be correct?

1. convert `[2, "a", { hello: "world" }]` to `["2", "a", '{ hello: "world" }']`
2. convert the first character of every string to a Number
3. order by that number

### Question

How do I implement a compare function that given any object, behaves exactly as the compare function from sort?

### Notes

Reading the ECMA specification:

- http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-array.prototype.sort

I now believe that if `comparefn` is `undefined`, then they use this algorithm as a default:

http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-sortcompare

Can someone confirm?

Comment: a is not a its a represented number in ASCII and Unicode ..

Comment: I have updated my question to be more clear, please have another look!

Comment: Check the algorithm in the specification: http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-array.prototype.sort

Comment: [here](http://trac.webkit.org/browser/trunk/Source/JavaScriptCore/runtime/ArrayPrototype.cpp?rev=138530#L647) is the webkit implementation of array sort. Don't know if that helps at all, but it looks like there are several different paths the sort could take based on contents

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Solution

After reading the ECMA spec and asking around, I arrived to a `defaultCompare` function that simulates the default behaviour of `Array.prototype.sort()` in chrome:

```
const defaultCompare = ( x, y ) => {
    //INFO: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort
    //ECMA specification: http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-sortcompare

    if( x === undefined && y === undefined )
        return 0;

    if( x === undefined )
        return 1;

    if( y === undefined )
        return -1;

    const xString = toString(x);
    const yString = toString(y);

    if( xString < yString )
        return -1;

    if( xString > yString )
        return 1;

    return 0;
};

const toString = obj => {
    //ECMA specification: http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-tostring

    if( obj === null )
        return "null";

    if( typeof obj === "boolean" ||  typeof obj === "number" )
        return (obj).toString();

    if( typeof obj === "string" )
        return obj;

    if( typeof obj === "symbol" )
        throw new TypeError();

    //we know we have an object. perhaps return JSON.stringify?
    return (obj).toString();
};

module.exports = defaultCompare;
```

### How can I test it?

You can test this function like the following:

```
const arr = [ undefined, null, 3, 2, 'B', 'a', 'b', 'A',
{ hello: "world"}, { goodnight: 'moon'} ]

assertEql( arr.sort(), arr.sort(defaultCompare) ); //true
```

The outputs should be equal, provided you test them in the same browser.

Comment: I think you have a typo in your second code block, there's a period that looks like it should be a comma. Also, since `Array.prototype.sort` sorts arrays in-place, your array will already be sorted once by the time you sort it with `defaultCompare`. You should make a copy of the array to use with the second compare function, to ensure that the pre-sorting doesn't affect the order of items.

Comment: @philraj good spot! I just submitted an edit with that dot and also replaced curly quotes into straight. Anyway, this seems to be a good default comparison function.

Comment: I'd like to mention that the the `undefined` checks are actually unnecessary because, whether you like it or not, `undefined` is never actually passed as a value to `compareFn` -- all `undefined` values are not compared to anything and instead always placed at the end of the array.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the `>` and `<` are enough for this.

You could take a look at an [implementation of Array.prototype.sort](https://github.com/mykeels/ArraysJS/blob/5fa47a2b3dbcede924fc04fa5442461f93c7ef53/Arrays.js#L164) I did a while back. It might help give you ideas for what you need.